# Cant Compile Kotlin Error - None of the following functions can be called

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Im trying to compile an app following this steps ->

https://github.com/wlvpn/ConsumerVPN-Android/blob/master/VPN%20SDK%20-%20documentation/SETUP.md

but in the last step that says " Library Initialization" when I copy that code at the Application file, the "SdkConfig" says that cannot be called like that. Im using the Kotlin method.

at Application.kt:

```
import com.gentlebreeze.vpn.sdk.IVpnSdk
import com.gentlebreeze.vpn.sdk.VpnSdk
import com.gentlebreeze.vpn.sdk.config.SdkConfig

override fun onCreate() {

    super.onCreate()

    vpnSdk = VpnSdk.init(this, SdkConfig(
        BuildConfig.ACCOUNT_NAME,
        BuildConfig.API_KEY,
        BuildConfig.AUTH_SUFFIX,
        BuildConfig.CLIENT,
        BuildConfig.BASE_HOSTNAME,
        BuildConfig.IP_GEO,
        BuildConfig.LOGIN_API,
        BuildConfig.REFRESH_API,
        BuildConfig.PROTOCOL_LIST_API,
        BuildConfig.SERVER_LIST_API
    ))

}

companion object {
    var vpnSdk: IVpnSdk? = null
}
```

}

at build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {

    buildConfigField 'String', 'ACCOUNT_NAME', '"xxxxx"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'AUTH_SUFFIX', '"xxxxx"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', '"xxxxxx"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'CLIENT', "\"Android-${versionName}b${versionCode}\""
    buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_HOSTNAME', '"https://api.colomovers.com/wlapi/%s"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'PROTOCOL_LIST_API', '"protocols"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'LOGIN_API', '"login"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'REFRESH_API', '"refresh"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_LIST_API', '"servers"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'IP_GEO', '"https://ipgeo.wlvpn.com/v2?apikey=xxxxxx"'
```

}

```
def versions = [
        os           : [
                support         : "1.0.0",
                lifecycle       : "2.0.0",
                constraintLayout: "1.1.3",
                material        : "1.1.0-alpha05",
                appCompat       : "1.1.0-alpha04"
        ],
        rxJava       : "2.2.5",
        rxAndroid    : "2.1.1",
        rxKotlin     : "2.3.0",
        rxBinding    : "3.0.0-alpha2",
        gson         : "2.8.5",
        dagger       : "2.21",
        retrofit     : "2.5.0",
        leakCanary   : "1.6.3",
        fresco       : "1.13.0",
        vpnSdk       : "1.5.3.39705@aar",
        nativeEncrypt: "1.0.036399@aar",
        timber       : "4.7.1",
        autoValue    : "1.6.2",
        loganSquare  : "1.3.7",
        evernoteJobs : "1.2.6",
        test         : [
                junit  : "4.12",
                mockito: "2.24.0"

        ]

]

dependencies{

    implementation("com.gentlebreeze.vpn.sdk:sdk:$versions.vpnSdk") {
    transitive = true
}
```

Error that appears:

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwW3G.png)

Its the only step that is missing to compile and try it. All other steps were added just as the link describe.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't link to code and error messages. [Edit] your question and put the relevant code and error messages in the question itself (_as text_, not as images).

Comment: Done the edition. Thanks, @Michael

Comment: Well, the documentation you were looking at appears to be out of date, because [their changelog](https://github.com/wlvpn/ConsumerVPN-Android/blob/master/VPN%20SDK%20-%20documentation/CHANGELOG.md) mentions that they've added another parameter (`logTag`) to the `SdkConfig` constructor. You can see the code for the available constructors directly in Android Studio by right-clicking and chosing Go To > Declaration.

Comment: great, already saw everything you comment but, any solution? @Michael

Comment: The solution is to pass another string to the constructor like it expects.

Comment: Sorry but i dont have any idea how to do it @Michael

Comment: It's a log tag string. Just pass any string you want. I suggest you read through the HTML format documentation that's included when you clone the github repo.